# No matching distribution found for PyQt5

Tags: python, pip, pyqt5, raspbian

I install a rasbian os on my vmware workstation and I am currently trying to install some packages and modules. I have a problem with **pip**. I try:

```
sudo pip install PyQt5
sudo pip3 install pyqt5
sudo python3 -m pip install PyQt5
```

I got the same error.

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyqt5 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyqt5
```

I try to install PyQt5 manually and for that I install `sip` with `sudo pip3 install sip` after that  I try to configure pyqt5 files with `python configure.py` but I got this error:

```
Error: Unable to import PyQt5.sip. Make sure you have configured SIP to create a private copy of the sip module.
```

I already install sip. But my main problem is about pip. It's not working like I expect

I'm not sure if it's about pip or it is a problem about operating system (or if it is about me).

`python --version`**:2.7.16**

`python3 --version`**:3.7.3**

`pip --version` I got the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 6, in <module>
    from pip._internal.main import main
ImportError: No module named main
```

`sudo pip --version` **:19.3.1**

`pip3 --version` **:18.1**

`lsb_release -a`

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:    10
Codename:   buster
```

Comment: use `sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5 python-pyqt5`

Comment: Thanks that worked but now I am getting **E: Unable to locate package python3-pyqt5=** error. I am trying to install 5.11.2 version of pyqt5.  `sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5=="5.11.2" python-pyqt5=="5.11.2" `

Comment: apt-get installs the system packages so you cannot choose the version. If you want to choose a version you must manually compile PyQt5 since pip does not offer PyQt5 for ARM.

Comment: Thanks I figure it out. Where can I learn more about ARM and other systems. (For now I'm not really sure what is ARM)

Comment: It is the type of processor used by the RPI.

Answer (score 1):

I had some error, when tried to install on virtualenv. It helped me:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Before I had 19.0.3 versin and upgraded to 22.0.4

then:

```
pip install PyQt5
```